# Table 'agentes' already exists

Tags: php

estoy recibiendo este error Error al ejecutar la consulta 0: Table 'agentes' already exists. La secuencia ocupa la posiciÃ³n 2
es muy curioso por que si cambio el nombre de la base de datos en la variable bd1 no me da el error

```
/**
 * Conecta a la base de datos.
 * @return boolean
 */
public function connect()
{
    $connected = FALSE;
    if (self::$link) {
        $connected = TRUE;
    } else if (class_exists('mysqli')) {             
        $bd1 = 'billimoy2';
        self::$link = @new mysqli(FS_DB_HOST, FS_DB_USER, FS_DB_PASS,FS_DB_NAME);
        self::$link->select_db($bd1);

        if (self::$link->connect_error) {
            self::$core_log->new_error(self::$link->connect_error);
            self::$link = NULL;
        } else {
            self::$link->set_charset('utf8');
            $connected = TRUE;
            if (!FS_FOREIGN_KEYS) {
                /// desactivamos las claves ajenas
                $this->exec("SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");
            }
            /// desactivamos el autocommit
            self::$link->autocommit(FALSE);
        }
    } else {
        self::$core_log->new_error('No tienes instalada la extensiÃ³n de PHP para MySQL.');
    }
    return $connected;
  }
/**
 * Conecta a la base de datos.
 * @return boolean
 */
public function connect()
{
    $connected = FALSE;
    if (self::$link) {
        $connected = TRUE;
    } else if (class_exists('mysqli')) {             
        $bd1 = 'billimoy2';
        self::$link = @new mysqli(FS_DB_HOST, FS_DB_USER, FS_DB_PASS,FS_DB_NAME);
        self::$link->select_db($bd1);

        if (self::$link->connect_error) {
            self::$core_log->new_error(self::$link->connect_error);
            self::$link = NULL;
        } else {
            self::$link->set_charset('utf8');
            $connected = TRUE;
            if (!FS_FOREIGN_KEYS) {
                /// desactivamos las claves ajenas
                $this->exec("SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");
            }
            /// desactivamos el autocommit
            self::$link->autocommit(FALSE);
        }
    } else {
        self::$core_log->new_error('No tienes instalada la extensiÃ³n de PHP para MySQL.');
    }
    return $connected;
  }
```

Comment: Por lo que estoy viendo en el error que te envia es que la tabla que creastes en la base de datos, con nombre 'agentes', ya existe en la base de datos. Podrias poner el codigo donde envias algun dato a esa tabla?

Comment: Por favor, puedes poner el resto del código donde utilizas la tabla  **agentes** ya que por el mensaje que colocas es como si estuvieras intentando crear de nuevo.

Comment: Si claro en tener un momento adjunto el código

Comment: este proyecto esta basado en facturascript adjunto enlace https://github.com/tomas33/facturascripts_2015